# Reading powerpoint pptx file in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, powerpoint, openxml

I was asked to find a way to use pptx as input for a game using cocos2D on iphone.
As far as I know pptx file use Office Open XML standard and should be fully readable, including informations on animations, in any programming language.

However I only find examples/tutorial using docx files and I would like to know if such documentation exists for pptx files.

I just spent two days on that topic, and I just can't find the strength to dive into Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Maybe [libopc](http://libopc.codeplex.com/documentation) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Maybe, but unfortunately I just couldn't find good tutorials on libopc and pptx files parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .pptx file is just a ZIP file containing some images files and XML files.  Wouter van Vugt's [free e-book](http://www.freetechbooks.com/open-xml-the-markup-explained-t666.html) will help you understand the XML.  Unfortunately the files contain a lot of boilerplate so it can take some time to find the bits you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the e-book, I'll read it and accept your answer if it's what I need